# How to make my iPhone app submit wall posts to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, ios4, xamarin.ios, social-networking

I have an iPhone app created with MonoTouch for pilots to log their flights.  I want to offer an option when a flight is saved that a post to their Facebook wall is made such as: "I flew in a XYZ aicraft today from A to B which took X hours."

Anyone have any suggestions how to implement this seemingly basic feature to submit saved records to the user's Facebook wall?  I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out these MonoTouch bindings for the Facebook iOS SDK:
https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/monotouch-facebook

I've not had a chance to try them yet but maybe they will help...

Update: The above repo is no longer being maintained. The Facebook binding in the monotouch-bindings repo should be used instead: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

Comment: +1 for the awesome work KevinMcmahon has done with MonoTouch.